# How can I use REGEXEXTRACT to return the text after the nth instance of a word in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm rather new to regex and I need some advice for how to tackle a particular problem. Apologies for any breaches in etiquette/terminology, I have only very basic knowledge of coding.

Let's say I have the following string in Cell A1 of spreadsheet "Test":

> Activity: Simon Says
>
> Handout: Wordsearch
>
> Activity: Musical Chairs
>
> Handout: Crossword
>
> Activity: Four Corners
>
> Handout: Color by Number

I can use the following formula to return the first activity, "Simon Says" in another cell:
`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(Test!A1, ("Activity:(.+)")),"\d* - ","")`

My question is, what regex can I use to return the second activity, which is to say, "Musical Chairs"? And the third?

Thank you to any who answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1&CHAR(10),"(?s)(?:.*?Activity: ){2}(.+?)\n")
```

[image]

Change 2 to 3 to get the 3rd occurrence.

You could also try the following formula without regex:

```cpp
=TRIM(INDEX(QUERY(WRAPROWS(SPLIT(A1,":"&CHAR(10)),2),"select Col2 where Col1 = 'Activity'"),2))
```

[image]